# Can a prepositional phrase act as the direct object?

Tags: prepositions

I'm new to Esperanto and starting to use transitive verbs. The book I'm using, *A Complete Grammar of Esperanto* (Ivy Kellerman, 1910), states that "a *transitive verb* expresses an act of the subject upon some person or thing". It also states that "the person or thing acted upon is called the *direct object* of a transitive verb, and is given the ending -n". This seems to imply that the direct object has to be a noun.

However, [Plena Ilustrita Vortaro de Esperanto](http://vortaro.net) gives the example sentence "*mi rigardis tra fenestro de mia domo*" [here](http://vortaro.net/#rigardi). Since "*rigardi*" is a transitive verb, the prepositional phrase "*tra fenestro de mia domo*" must be acting as the direct object. So it seems valid to use a prepositional phrases as the direct object.

And just for comparison's sake, if the sentence was instead "*mi rigardis*", it would be invalid because "*rigardi*" is transitive. And if the sentence was instead "mi rigardis la ĉevalojn tra fenestro de mia domo", the direct object would now be "*la ĉevalojn*" instead of the prepositional phrase.

**Could someone provide an official or a credible source which explicitly outlines this grammatical rule?** I'm trying to learn Esperanto with a firm understanding of all the constructed grammatical rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transitive verb just means that the verb is an action upon something else. However you don’t necessarily have to mention the object and it can just be implied. For example:

> What are you doing?
>
> I am reading.

In this case *to read* is a transitive verb. The person asking the question will assume the other person is reading *something*, probably a book, so the verb is still transitive even though the sentence doesn’t have an explicit object.

This is the same thing that is happening with your example sentence. The *tra* part is not the object. Instead the object is not explicitly mentioned and the reader is supposed to assume that the person is looking at *something* out of the window, even though they don’t explicitly mention it.

> Kion vi faras?
>
> Mi rigardas [ion] tra la fenestro.

Answer (score 0):

[*Plena manlibro de Esperanta gramatiko*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) (PMEG) is your friend. It's available online, as downloadable html site and as PDF. It explains the grammar of Esperanto thoroughly… in Esperanto, so it might have a steep learning curve.

PMEG, usually called by its nickname *Pomego*, is constantly updated. The latest revision is from 2019-10-16.

To answer your question see the [*tra*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/tra.html) examples in PMEG, especially the one with the verb *rigardi*.

Comment: I don’t think any of the examples that you linked to in PMEG show *tra* is the direct object.

Comment: There is an example in PMEG with _rigardi tra…_. You're right, technically the tra-part isn't an object. I've edited my answer.